# netbeans c++ ppl.h and paralel_for

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin

I am very new to handling of IDEs, libraries, complilers etc and I wasn't able to get to an answer anywhere.

I have a program with include ppl.h, using namespace concurency and parallel_for loop. These were automatically included on VS2017. On a different pc I have only netbeans portable with minGW32. I cannot find ppl.h for download. Is it a part of some VS package? How can I get it running on netbeans portable, or use something simillar to parallel_for loop?

Thank you

Comment: ppl.h is part of the Microsoft Parallel Patterns Library https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx . It should be possible to download or copy it from a working VS2017 install and link it in.

Comment: I was able to get to parallel_for.h at https://github.com/01org/tbb. I have tbb directory in include path, and I have #include <parallel_for.h> (successfuly, no error). But later in code parallel_for is unidendified. What am I missing?

Comment: Umm, are  you mixing TBB with PPL? To some degree, you can use TBB with PPL code, but it's not something I would recommend as a stable direction to build on in the future. See https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#reference/appendices/ppl_compatibility.html If you can not use the microsoft compiler toolset, you can use Intel's c++ compiler toolset instead and switch entirely to TBB's. You may have to go over your code and translate the concepts to TBB, but atleast it will be more portable.